# How to implement a dialogue system without stalling the main loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua

I'm interested in implementing a dialogue system similar to what is being done here http://fungusdocs.snozbot.com/lua_controlling_fungus.html .

```
-- Display text in a SayDialog
say("Hi there")
say "This syntax also works for say commands"
-- Display a list of options in a MenuDialog
-- (Note the curly braces here!)
local choice = choose{ "Go left", "Go right" }
if choice == 1 then
    say("You chose left")
elseif choice == 2 then
    say("You chose right")
end
```

My takeaway from this lua code snippet is that the code is very easy to write and follow along, and I look to use a similar approach. **What I wonder is how this can be implemented without stalling the engine code while waiting for a choice.**

the function call *choose{ "Go left", "Go right" }* return a value which makes me want to say that this is a synchronous call. Since we're calling the engine code synchronous we then halt the engine, yet this function call should not be the one directly answering the question - I believe that it needs to be answered in the regular main loop as not to interfere with the rest of the program.

To my understanding the only way to solve this would be to rely on multi-threading. to have the script handled on a separate thread that on the choose call first adds a prompt, then waits for the prompt to be answered, fetch the result, and then continues executing the lua script.

**What would be a good way to solve this without making the lua code cumbersome to work with?**

Comment: Good point. I'm working in a C++ system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd run the blocking code in Lua thread (coroutine).

Your `choose{}` call would yield internally, and the app would resume that thread periodically on external events (input/render/whatever). That way you can have the main loop running freely, taking results from that dialog on nearest iteration after dialog is ready.

The object serving `choose{}` call might trigger some event on completion, which might be monitored by application's bigger system, the same system that would wait for completion of other  asynchronous tasks (file loaded, http request served, etc).

Comment: When you talk about _Lua thread (coroutine)_, **do you mean running a separate thread on the main c++ app, or doing a coroutine in Lua?**
My idea so far is to have the whole dialogue execute on a separate lua thread in my c++ app. Once `choose` is called it will: **1.** set the chatbox to the appropriate question. **2.** loop and wait for the chatbox to be cleared. **3.** return the the question value from the chatbox back to lua. Mutex protection when dealing with the chatbox. **would this be similar to the coroutine solution?**

Comment: @John Smith, the Lua thread is not a truly parallel process. It's another thread of execution of Lua code, think of it as of separate stack and registers set on the same virtual machine. That thread is used to express your dialog flow linearly, though it will actually break out and return back into that flow many times, continuing execution at the same point where it had to break.

Comment: If you go with native thread, then you don't need coroutines. You need something that will allow you to check (in a non-blocking way) if dialog is complete or not, and then grab results from that dialog. That means running dialog in a separate native thread, having some flow context associated with dialog, mutexes/cond_vars to safely share that state with app's main thread, etc. Really, it's not a big deal, do as you feel more comfortable.

Comment: @Vlad - the method you described (polling that coroutine periodically) corresponds to OP's phrase "making the lua code cumbersome" :-)

Comment: It all depends on the abstraction you build :)